# Retrieving JSON data

Tags: php, json, import

I have a slight problem. I want to import some JSON coded data into my page using PHP. All works fine except one thing. The nodes in the original JSON string, some of them are called for example "[0]", "[1]", etc. Now the number of these depends on the number of elements and is variable.
So, what I wanted to do... I have a variable "$count" which contains the number of elements. Then I wanted to decode the JSON data as follows:

```
$count = $data->metadata->count;

for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){
$magnitude = $data->features->[$i]->properties->mag;
}
```

But the problem is that it gives me an error once there is the "[$i]". Does anyone know how to change it so that for example in case there are 5 values, it runs 5 times the "for" statement and gets data from:

```
$magnitude = $data->features->[0]->properties->mag;
$magnitude = $data->features->[1]->properties->mag;
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this.

```
$magnitude = array();

foreach($data->features as $features){
    $magnitude[] = $features->properties->mag;
}

print_r($magnitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Ben Fortune should work, but here is a more direct fix for your original code.  Since `$data->features` is not an array but an object, you need to access numerical properties with `{}`, not `[]`.  In addition, since you're working with a 0-based set, you should change the condition in the `if` statement from `$i <= $count` to `$i < $count`.

```
$count = $data->metadata->count;

for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $magnitude = $data->features->{$i}->properties->mag;
    // Do stuff with $magnitude...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$magnitude = $data->features->{'['.$i.']'}->properties->mag;
```